# Move image with mouse cursor in Java applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, cursor, mouse

I've been trying to teach myself Java recently and as part of the process I'm working on a Calorie Calculator applet.
Just to make things more fun I was thinking to use the picture of a smartphone as the background image.
What I want to know is: say I also had a picture of a stylus pen; any way I could make that move with the mouse once I've clicked on it? Preferably this image would replace the mouse cursor (though not mandatory). It should stick to the mouse cursor until the applet is closed, regardless of any other events occurring (clicking other images, buttons, text areas etc.)
I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Have you tried something?? Post your attempt

Comment: *"I've been trying to teach myself Java.."*  Avoid applets for the moment then.  This [blog article](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) explains why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..any way I could make that move with the mouse once I've clicked on it?

The main component needs a `MouseListener`. See [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for details.

> Preferably this image would replace the mouse cursor (though not mandatory).

Look to the [`Cursor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html) API for that.

---

This sounds like a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/155831).

What you might actually be looking for is [Drag and Drop and Data Transfer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html).